# InternetExplorer.Application Clear Content

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I have the below code to open a window in internet explorer and show the progress
    to the user.

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objExplorer.navigate "about:blank" 
objExplorer.document.write  "Processing record 1 of 1000"
```

I after the above code i'd like to clear the contents of the document and write something else but when the below the content doesn't get clear.

```
objExplorer.document.Clear
```

Is there a way to clear the content without closing the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the below code does the trick;

```
objExplorer.Refresh
```